# Solve $x^2=b \mod m$ congruence equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to solve $x^2=b \mod m$ type of equations. 
I have, for example, have to find all $a$ for which $a^2= 3 \mod 11$ and I have a couple of very basic (I'm sorry!) questions

1. How do I use quadratic reciprocity to prove that this has a
   solution?
2. I can see that 5 and 6 are solutions and I think that it suffices to
   try all numbers from 0 to 10 but I do not understand why (can I try
   even less numbers?). If $a$ was not squared I clearly see that the
   numbers from 0 to 10 generate all congruence classes but with the
   square there I do not get all congruence classes for $\pmod {11}$.
3. Is there a general way to solve this if I have to try more than 11
   numbers?

Sorry for my basic questions and thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: For $a$ not congruent to $0$ modulo an odd prime $p$, one can show fairly easily that the congruence has either $2$ solutions (one of which is the negative of the other). so if by luck you find one, the other is automatic, and you know there are no more. Sure, you can use Reciprocity to show that $x^2\equiv 3\pmod{11}$ has a solution, but that's severe overkill for such a puny prime. For some classes of primes $p$, there are nice fast deterministic algorithms for finding a solution. For the rest, there are good probabilistic algorithms. Don't know exactly how much detail you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Using quadratic reciporcity:

$$\left(\frac{3}{11}\right)=-\left(\frac{11}{3}\right)=-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-(-1)=1$$

You can always try *only* with the elements

$$\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,\frac{p-1}{2}\right\}$$

as the other elements are negatives of some of the above ones and thus squared...

Answer (score 1):

There are reasonably efficient algorithms to compute square roots mod $\rm\,p,\:$ e.g. the [Tonelli-Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and [Cipolla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm) algorithms. Using CRT and Hensel lifting yields an algorithm for arbitrary modulus.